# Почему в консольном PHP программы запускаются непоследовательно?

Tags: php, консоль

Предположим, что у меня есть некоторый массив $models примерно такого вида:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["props"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "prop0"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "prop1"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["props"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "prop2"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "prop3"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["props"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "prop4"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "prop5"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Я работаю с этим массивом с помощью следующего метода:

```
private function getPropData($name, $filename = self::FILE)
    {
        exec('render ' . $name);
        if (!file_exists($filename))
            echo 'Not exist' . PHP_EOL;
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ($handle === false)
            throw new Exception('Fail');
        $contents = json_decode(fread($handle, filesize($filename)));
        fclose($handle);
        if (empty($contents)) {
            throw new Exception('File is empty');
        }
        return $contents;
}
```

Этот метод я запускаю в цикле для каждого `prop` (`prop1`,`prop2`...), и значение `prop` передается в переменную `$name`. `exec` - выполняет команду `render prop1` (пример для `prop1`), который записывает в файл, указанный в `self::FILE`(например, `/var/www/rendered/file.txt`), с флагом `w` (каждый раз данные перезаписываются) данные в формате `JSON`. Далее в этом методе просто открывается файл, декодируются и возвращаются данные. Выполнение программы `render` для каждого вызова занимает примерно 5 секунд. 
Проблема заключается в том, что когда я запускаю все это дело в цикле для каждого `prop`, то для некоторых значений `exec` не запускается или запускается, файл создается, но выдается исключение `"File is empty"`. Возможно программа `render` не успевает закончить свою работу и `php` уже пытается открыть файл, но вроде же должно все последовательно происходить. Причем, если я буду сидеть и вручную в консоли писать по очереди

```
render prop1
render prop2
...
```

то файл `/var/www/rendered/file.txt` будет корректно для каждого `prop` перезаписываться.
Помогите разобраться, в чем дело.

Comment: Вероятно ошибка в команде `render ` тк она не записывает данные в файл. Не надо использовать устаревшие функции работы с файлами без веской причины. В php5 есть функции file_get_contents и file_put_contents, которые покрывают 99% потребностей разработчиков, к тому же с ними сложнее совершить ошибку.

Comment: но когда я вручную прописываю для каждого prop команду render, то все работает, данные в файл записываются при каждой команде.

Comment: @MarselArduanov Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно ошибка в команде render т.к. она не записывает данные в файл.

Не надо использовать устаревшие функции работы с файлами без веской причины. В php5 есть функции file_get_contents и file_put_contents, которые покрывают 99% потребностей разработчиков, к тому же с ними сложнее совершить ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

При запуске **exec** создается процесс который никак не связан с выполнением вашего скрипта, а значит не будет его ждать, в цикле возможно наложение логики между процессами